# What is the best method of cleaning query strings?

Tags: php, security

What is the best and method of ensuring that `$page` and `$getVars` are clean and safe?

```
//fetch the passed request
$request = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

//parse the page request and other GET variables
$parsed = explode('&', $request);

//the page is the first element
$page = array_shift($parsed);

//the rest of the array are GET statements, parse them out;
$getVars = array();
foreach($parsed as $argument)
{
  //split GET vars along '=' symbol to seperate the variable and its value
  list($variable, $value) = explode('=', $argument);
  $getVars[$variable] = $value;
}
```

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Comment: thanks. just started learning - it was like this in the tutorial I was looking at.

Comment: My personal preference for cleaning is Arm & Hammer or Tide.

Comment: OK, start by throwing out whatever tutorial you saw this code in.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you just want to use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` as the others already have mentioned.

In order to verify and clean your variables, you should have a look at [PHP's Data Filtering functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) which were introduced in PHP 5.2. You also find some examples [in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) similar to this:

```
if (filter_var('0.0.0.0', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false) {
    // IP address is valid
}
```

or

```
$options = array(
    'options' => array(
        'min_range' => 0,
        'max_range' => 2,
    )
);

if (filter_var(1, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options) !== false) {
    // 1 is between 0 and 2
}
```